# Mechanize submit

Tags: python, testing, mechanize

We have a form which has a few separate submit buttons which do different actions.  The problem is I have a couple of buttons which have the following HTML:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submitLink" title="Submit" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete" class="submitLink" title="Delete" />
```

Now you can't locate an element by value with the standard find_control function.  So I wrote a predicate function which would find my element, which I was then hoping to click in the following manner:

```
submit_button = self.br.form.find_control(predicate=submit_button_finder)
self.br.submit(submit_button)
```

However both submit and click internally call find element, and neither method allows you to add in the predicate keyword, so a call like this doesn't work either:

```
self.br.submit(predicate=submit_button_finder)
```

Is there anything I'm missing?!?

Update:

Added a helper function to retrieve all elements which meet the criteria as such:

```
def find_controls(self, name=None, type=None, kind=None, id=None, predicate=None, label=None):

  i = 0
  results = []

  try :
    while(True):
      results.append(self.browswer.find_control(name, type, kind, id, predicate, label, nr=i))
      i += 1
  except Exception as e: #Exception tossed if control not found
    pass
  return results
```

Then replaced the following lines:

```
submit_button = self.br.form.find_control(predicate=submit_button_finder)
self.br.submit(submit_button)
```

With:

```
submit_button = self.br.form.find_control(predicate=submit_button_finder)
submit_buttons = self.find_controls(type="submit")
for button in submit_buttons[:]:
  if (button != submit_button) : self.br.form.controls.remove(button)
self.br.submit()
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you shouldn't have two buttons with the same name on a page. That might be part of your problem.

Comment: @Alex I unfortunately have no control over that though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fairly ghetto workaround is to manually iterate through all the controls in the form in question and then remove the controls from the form that you do not want based on criteria. For instance:

```
for each in form.controls[:]:
  if each not "some criteria":
    form.controls.remove(each)
```

The best idea here is to limit the controls that you're iterating through to SubmitControl objects ONLY. This way, you'll limit the form to one submit button, and the browser.submit() method will have no choice of what to click.

Comment: Added a helper function to allow us pull all elements given a location strategy.  Then removed as you suggested.  Modifying original question to include answer.